# how to check sql query before save in yii

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, yii

I am trying to insert a record in my table using yii model. It shows no error but no record is being added. Now I want to check the sql query before save in yii. Is there any way i can do that?

Here is a part of my code.

```
$form = new BaseSysRegistration();
$form->attributes = $_POST['BaseSysRegistration'];
$form->of_passport_number = $_POST['of_passport_number'];
$form->password2 = $_POST['BaseSysRegistration']['password'];
$form->email_addr = $_POST['BaseSysRegistration']['email_addr'];
$form->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$form = new BaseSysRegistration();
$form->attributes = $_POST['BaseSysRegistration'];
$form->of_passport_number = $_POST['of_passport_number'];
$form->password2 = $_POST['BaseSysRegistration']['password'];
$form->email_addr = $_POST['BaseSysRegistration']['email_addr'];

if ($form ->save(true)) { // Return if the model is saved. (With true validate the fields)
     Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'All correct');
     $this->redirect(array('index'));
}else{
     Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', 'Error');
     $this->redirect(array('update', 'model' => $form));
}
```